# Merging directories and keep files that have more lines

Tags: file, file-system, bash

**Goal**

My goal is to merge directories. Whenever a file has the same name in two or more directories, then only the one that has the highest number of lines should be kept. If both files have the same number of files and differ then an error message should be thrown. Note that files having more lines are also bigger (in my specific case) which might be another way to compare files having the same name.

**My Code**

Here is my code that I think works fine

```
### Parameters ###

GeneralPath="/Users/remi/Documents/Biologie/Vancouver/PhD/Thesis/BackgroundSelection/Simulations/s_and_Pi/outputs/4.0.2_1.0.5/"

cd ${GeneralPath} 
Directories=( HR OR OS ) # Array of directories ot be merged with the destination directory
Destination=HS
errorFile="${GeneralPath}MergeDirs.err"


### Do Stuff ###

for d in ${Directories[@]};do
    echo "${d}"
    cd $d
    for f in *; do
        echo "      ${f}"
        if [ ! -f "../${Destination}/${f}" ];then
            echo cp1
            cp ${f} ../${Destination}/
        else
            nblinesFrom=$(wc -l ${f} | awk -F" " '{print $1}')
            nblinesDest=$(wc -l "../${Destination}/${f}" | awk -F" " '{print $1}')
            if [ ${nblinesFrom} -gt ${nblinesDest} ]; then
                echo cp2
                cp ${f} ../${Destination}/
            elif [ ${nblinesDest} -gt ${nblinesFrom} ];then
                echo "Destination is bigger - nothing to do"
            else
                DoTheyDiffer=$(diff ${f} "../${Destination}/${f}" | wc -l)
                if [ ${DoTheyDiffer} -gt 0 ];then
                    echo "${f} and ../${Destination}/${f} diff but have the same number of lines" >> ${errorFile}
                fi
            fi
        fi
    done
    cd ..
done
```

My code seems quite complicated and I feel like a good combinaison of `find -exec`, `awk`, `cp` and `diff` might do something much more fancy.

Answer (score 1):

- [Use More Quotes™](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes).
- Use a [shebang line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10383546/96588) (disclosure: I wrote that answer).
- Don't use single character variables. Maintainability is the most important feature of code.
- Rather than `echo cp1` etc., simply use `cp -v` to print every copy command verbatim.
- You don't need to count the number of lines that `diff` returns, you can simply do `if diff foo bar`, or the safer option:

  ```
  diff foo bar
  exit_code=$?
  if [ "$exit_code" -eq 0 ]
  then
      [no difference]
  elif [ "$exit_code" -eq 1 ]
  then
      [difference]
  else
      exit "$exit_code" # WTF
  fi
  ```
- Some people love mixing languages. I think `cut -d' ' -f1` is much nicer than even a short `awk` script.
- If you pass the file to `wc` on standard input, it doesn't print the filename, and so you don't need to process the output at all: `wc -l < /path`
- You can use `if cp --no-clobber source destination` to try copying the file instead of checking whether the target exists.
- I'm not sure I understand why you're copying rather than moving files (unless this is a one-off script, which you're not going to test, and it's only going to take a few seconds anyway).
- Be wary of using `cd` in scripts. It changes the context in a significant way, and makes it harder to reason about what the script will do. Instead, simply do `for path in "$directory"/*.
- I can definitely recommend `set -o errexit -o noclobber -o nounset -o pipefail`. You could also use `-o xtrace` to make all those logging commands obsolete.
- A common convention to get used to is to never end paths with a slash. Firstly because `cp a b/` and `cp a b` and the same as long as `b` is a directory, and secondly because it makes it more natural to concatenate paths without ending up with double slashes.